# Curious Spring AOP Exception

Tags: java, xml, spring, aop, aspectj

I'm trying to get my first-ever Spring AOP-based MethodInterceptors working, and am getting some bizarre exceptions with my **ultra-simple** XML configuration.

I have a class named `Food` which has a method called `eat(ConsumptionRate rate)` that takes an object of type `ConsumptionRate` as its sole parameter; every time that specific method (`Food::eat(ConsumptionRate)`) gets invoked, I want a `MethodInterceptor` to execute "around it":

```
public class FoodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor
{
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation method)
    {
        try 
        {
            // Do some stuff before target method executes

            Object result = method.proceed();
            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Do some stuff after target method executes.
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my xml config (`aop-config.xml`) in its entirety:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

<bean name="foodInterceptor" class="com.me.foodproject.core.FoodInterceptor"/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="foodInterceptor"
        pointcut="execution(public * Food.eat(..))"/>
</aop:config>
```

Project builds fine (compiles, etc.), but when I run it I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: Food [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

My only *guess* is that the pattern specified in the pointcut attribute is somehow wrong (maybe I need to include `ConsumptionRate` in it somehow). But the documentation for this XML Schema has been nearly impossible to find, and I'm stumbling around in the dark here.

Anybody have any suggestions or see something that jumps out at them? Thanks in advance!

**As an aside**, if someone knows of a site or any literature that documents all of these `<aop>` tags and their attributes, please let me know.  Chapter 6 of the Spring AOP reference has been recommended to me, and although that is a very comprehensive tutorial, it is just full of examples, and does not document the entire xml schema.

Comment: You're not looking for schema info, you're looking for pointcut syntax, which is covered in the Spring AOP docs. Is there a class `Food` without a package? (Well, for *this* problem, you need the pointcut syntax :)

Comment: Hi @Dave - thanks for the response. Can I ask what you mean when you ask "Is there a class Food without a package?" Everything compiles perfectly fine, its just at runtime when things go haywire.

Comment: I mean "Is there a `Food` class, without a package?" because that's how you've defined the pointcut. The config file won't care if it compiles fine--Spring AOP happens at execution, not compilation, unlike AspectJ.

Comment: Ahhh, I wasn't using the fully-qualified package name. Thanks @Dave, if you make your response an answer I'll check it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're using the fully-qualified class name (or a wildcard version that also matches), otherwise the class scanner won't find it.